# How do I reload all JavaScript on the page using oncomplete?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I want to reload all this javascript/jquery. I tried sticking it in a function but it doesn't seem to be rendering properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    console.log('jQuery loaded successfully');

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('[id$=opportunityTable]').dataTable(
        {
            "bJQueryUI": true
        });
    });

    //var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
    console.log('{!dataString}');
    var tooltipMap = $.parseJSON('{!mapJSON}');
    console.log('tooltipMap');

    $(function()
    {

        $('#from').datepicker(
        {
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function(selectedDate)
            {
                $('#to').datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });

        $('#to').datepicker(
        {
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function(selectedDate)
            {
                $('#from').datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
        console.log('Datepicker configuration loaded successfully');

        /*setting Default jQuery Dates*/
        $('#from').datepicker('setDate', '0');
        $('#to').datepicker('setDate', '+90d');
        console.log('Datepicker default dates loaded successfully');


        /*jQuery to handle filter Click*/
        $("#filterButton").click(function()
        {
            passDateValues($('#from').val(), $('#to').val());
            console.log('Filter Button click event got fired');
            console.log('Parameters Passed: ' + 'From: ' + $('#from').val() + '  To: ' + $('#to').val());
        });

        $('[id$=filterHelpTextID]').tooltip();
        console.log('Tooltip loaded successfully');

        //heatMap();

        $('#container').highcharts(
        {

            chart:
            {
                type: 'heatmap',
                marginTop: 100,
                marginBottom: 25,
                plotBorderWidth: 1
            },


            title:
            {
                text: ' '

            },

            exporting:
            {
                sourceWidth: 2000,
                sourceHeight: 700,
            },

            xAxis: [
            {
                categories:
                {!fieldLabels
                },
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridZIndex: 4,
                opposite: true,

                labels:
                {
                    autoRotation: false
                }
            }],

            yAxis:
            {
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                gridZIndex: 4,
                categories:
                {!OpportunityNames
                },
                title:
                {
                    text: 'Opportunity'
                },


            },

            plotOptions:
            {
                series:
                {
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    colors: ['#FFFFFF', '#9BC2E6', '#FFE699', '#A9D08E', '#AEAAAA', '#CC66FF'],
                    states:
                    {
                        hover:
                        {
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }

            },

            legend:
            {
                enabled: false,
            },

            series: [
            {
                name: 'Heat Map Values',
                borderWidth: 1,
                data:
                {!dataString
                },
            }],


            credits:
            {
                enabled: false
            }


        });
    });
</script>
```

As mentioned, I tried putting all the code into one javascript function and calling it during oncomplete.Does the no.Conflict() affect this?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to be more explicit about what you mean by *not rendering properly*.

Comment: What you mean by reload? Once the page is loaded, again you want to reload the page or call again the JavaScript functions? And even if you want to call the  JavaScript functions, what would it serve as its already done its job one time?

Answer (score 3):

As per the title, you're looking to call a JS function on a VF page. Try this if it helps if you're looking for calling the JS function one time.

```
<apex:actionSupport oncomplete="callJSfunction();" event="onchange" action="{!SomeApexMethodIfAny}" rerender="SomeId" />

<script>

function callJSfunction()
{

//Your whole above JS code

}

<script>
</apex>
```

**If you're looking to call the JavaScript one time, above way should help you.**

Comment: You should look at [Self-Executing Anonymous Functions](http://markdalgleish.com/2011/03/self-executing-anonymous-functions/). They clean up your `Javascript` quite a lot, especially if you incorporate `jQuery`.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to reload the page you can use

window.location.reload

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46725)

Comment: @VigneshwaranG why wouldn't this be a possible approach/answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try putting all script in `<apex:outputpanel>` and try rerendering that panel instead of using oncomplete.